# Serial port data received event handler firing more than once

Tags: c#, gsm

I have created a program that reads the messages from a Wireless Cellular Modem (ZTE MF 190) and then performs further functions on the received message. The issue I am facing is that the datareceived event handler is firing multiple times for each message received while the requirement is to fire it only once.

The code is shown here:

```
_serialPort.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(_serialPort_DataReceived);
```

The above code is to activate the listener.

```
private void _serialPort_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    read_sms();        
}
```

The above event handler executes the necessary operations but it is being fired more than once. How to limit it to execute only once.

Comment: There's no way for you to guarantee that the data will be received all at once. You'll have to build in a buffering system.

Comment: @itsme86 i am trying to read the data at a particular location not all at once. is there any alternate way ?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. I don't see anything in your question about location.

Answer (score 1):

The serialport data received event is telling you that some characters have been received.  It is not telling you that an entire sms has been received.  Therefore,

1. It does not make sense to invoke a method called "read_sms()" as a result of this event firing, because you have absolutely no guarantees that an entire sms is available to read.
2. You should in fact expect the event to be triggered many times, as more characters arrive, until the entire sms has been received.

You need to store the received characters in a buffer and you need to parse the buffer in order to determine whether it contains an sms in its entirety.

Comment: okay that makes much more sense now. Thank u so much. I will get on it right away :)